# Proper way to use the different weights of a Google font

Tags: css, fonts

[Google fonts like Open Sans](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Open+Sans?selection.family=Open+Sans) come in different weights each one labelled both as a word (for example "regular") and a number ("400"). But which one of these two "formats" should be used in our CSS/SCSS? Are they equivalent?

[image]

Comment: Both are acceptable --> https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/font-weight

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use either or. No difference at all. Just pick one and go with that type of value for all of your fonts to keep it consistent.

I use the numbers just because that's what makes sense to me. Most fonts will have the 400 for normal and 700 for bold.